# useState and changes in the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to understand what happens when you have both `props` and `useState` in one component.

I wrote little example of it which has one parent component that prints its numbers with another child component -

```
const MyNumbers = (props) => {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState([...props.arr]);

  function changeNumbers() {
    setNumbers((nums) => [...nums.map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10))]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="MyNumbers">
      <div>
        <button onClick={changeNumbers}>Chane numbers</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {numbers.map((num, idx) => (
          <SingleNumber key={idx} num={num}></SingleNumber>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const SingleNumber = (props) => {
  const [num] = useState(props.num);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect called");
  });
  return <h3>The number is {num}</h3>;
};
```

[Here is the above demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-v4irs?file=/src/index.js:287-773)

The `SingleNumber` component uses `useState` and as you can see clicking on the "Change numbers" action doesn't change the values in the children component.

But when I wrote almost the same code but now `SingleNumber` doesn't use `useState` then clicking on the "Change numbers" changes all the values in the children component ([like in this demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-mxmcc?file=/src/index.js)).

Is it correct to say that a function component with a `useState` renders once and then only changed if the state changed but not if the `props` changed ?

Comment: The component re-renders each time. But you have essentially *cached* the value in the local state and output that all the time. The value you pass to `useState` is only used for when the component is mounted (*first time only*).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OFC the component "rerenders" when the props change, the `useEffect` hook in `SingleNumber` is ***showing*** you that the "render phase" is run each time the props change.... effects are run each time the component is rendered.

[image]

```
const SingleNumber = (props) => {
  const [num] = useState(props.num);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect called"); // <-- logged each time the component renders
  });
  return <h3>The number is {num}</h3>;
};
```

If you added a dependency on `props.num` and updated the local state (don't *actually* do this, it's an anti-pattern in react!), you'll see the UI again update each time the props update.

To answer your queston:

> Is it correct to say that a function component with a `useState` renders
> once and then only changed if the state changed but not if the `props`
> changed?

No, this is not technically correct to say if "render" to you means strictly react rendered the component to compute a diff, react components rerender when state or props update. Yes, if "render" more generally means you visually see the UI update.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `useState` it returns an array with two values in it:

1. The current value of that bit of the state
2. A function to update the state

If there is no current value when it sets the state to the default value and returns that.

(The default value is the argument you pass to `useState`).

---

If you change the values of `props` in your example, then the component rerenders.

`useState` returns *the current value of that bit of the state*. The state **has** a value, so it doesn't do anything with the argument you pass to `useState`. It doesn't matter that that value has changed.

Since nothing else has changed in the output, the rerendered component doesn't update the DOM.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `useState` in `SingleNumber`.

because `useState` called only once when it rendered.

```js
const SingleNumber = (props) => {
  // const [num] = useState(props.num);
  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log("useEffect called");
  // });
  return <h3>The number is {props.num}</h3>;
};
```

if you want to use `useState`, you can use like this.

```js
const SingleNumber = (props) => {
   const [num, setNum] = useState(props.num);
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("useEffect called");
     setNum(props.num);

   }, [props.num]);
  return <h3>The number is {num}</h3>;
};
```

Comment: `useEffect` conditional on the changes props is the easiest way to manage this.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it correct to say that a function component with a useState renders once and then only changed if the state changed but not if the props changed?

No, it does **rerender** but doesn't **commit** the changes.

When parent component `MyNumbers` re-renders by clicking `changeNumbers`, by default (unless `React.memo` used) all its children components (like `SingleNumber`) will be re-render.

Now when `SingleNumber` rerenders, notice [`useState` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

> During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as the value passed as the first argument (initialState).

You initial the state `useState(props.num)` but it can only be changed by calling the setter function, therefore the state `num` won't change because you never calling the setter.

But it **will** rerender on parent render as mentioned above (notice the `useEffect` logs).